# Class App\User contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract

Tags: laravel

I saw this error for the first time and don't really know what to do about it. 
When I tried to register a new user on my website and when I clicked on submit button it shows:

> FatalErrorException in User.php line 11:
>   Class App\User contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifierName, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifier, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthPassword, ...)

**User Model:**

```
<?php 
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';   
}
```

What is it trying to say, I don't understand. Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are implementing `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`. This is interface and requires your `User` class to have some required methods:

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName();
public function getAuthIdentifier();
public function getAuthPassword();
public function getRememberToken();
public function setRememberToken($value);
public function getRememberTokenName();
```

If you are trying to make default `User` model, you should use `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` and extend it instead of `Model` class. There is no need to implement `Authenticatable` interfase.

Comment: I am trying to make default user model, so I added : use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; and also changed the class name declaration to : class User extends Authenticatable , but it shows error: Cannot use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable because the name is already in use . Any clue??

Comment: You removed `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` from uses ?

Comment: Oh I didn't. Now I did and error is gone now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to either extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, or use `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait in your class

**UPDATE**

You need to extend Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User like this

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also make sure you don't have native Laravel's App\User model in you app folder, named User.php

Comment: I used Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User instead of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, now it shows : Cannot declare class App\User because the name is already in use also tried your second option, it didn't work either. Any clue?